# Comma before the word 'and'

Tags: punctuation, commas

Do I need to place a comma before 'and'?

'Trelawny buys a schooner(,)and, with the help of Long John Silver, he puts together a crew.'

Comment: Wars have been fought over less.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comma after or before "parenthetic" and?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121646/comma-after-or-before-parenthetic-and) << ...  Nana led us to the living room, and with Mongai's _Take Me Somewhere Nice_ playing on in the background, we started on the Scotch .... >>